# Magento does not support using unicode characters as URL key

Tags: magento

How to make Magento accept unicode utf-8 characters in the url key ?
what I want to achieve is something like this, in different non-English languages

```
http://www.magento-site.com/ساعة-يد-كاسيو-2015.html
```

I am using Magento 1.9 
how can I do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an extension named [URL Key Master](http://magendev.com/magento-extentions/url-key-master.html) which adds the support for Unicode URL Key for Product, Category and also CMS Pages to Magento.

Take a look at [Demo site](http://marsonworld.com/) or search for "URL Key Master by Magendev" in magento connect.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of files responsible for allowing UTF-8 characters at the 'URL Key'. These files include:

```
\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Cms\Page\Edit\Tab\Main.php
\app\code\core\Mage\Cms\Model\Resource\Page.php
\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Category.php
\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Product\Url.php
\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Request\Http.php
```

Use this tutorial for details on how to make Magento accept [Unicode URL Key for Products, Categories, CMS Pages](http://killerwhalesoft.com/blog/magento-unicode-url-key-products-categories-cms-pages/)